# GoogleSignInApi signing in not succeeding with RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, google-signin

When trying to use the GoogleSignInApi for my app, it throws this execption: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }}` I don't know where this error comes from, and I'm wondering how to fix it.

I have programmed this so far:

```
public void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleclient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d("TAG", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        if(acct != null){
            Log.d("oke", acct.getDisplayName());
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

This code gives me the error that I mentioned in the title.
I don't know why this happens, and in my other project, everything was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake:

you have to do the

```
setContentView(view);
```

before initializing the GoogleSignInApi!